# How to resolve a steam custom vanity profile URL to steamID64

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam, steam-web-api

I am using Steam's API to fetch player data. To do this you need to provide a steamID64 (`76561197960435530`) like this example shown [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API): `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=440&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561197960435530` however this can sometimes be tricky for my users as many have their own custom vanity url which does not provide the steamID64 for them to easily input. I know they could use use a website to look it up but this is not an option.

How would I take the input of a custom vanity profile URL like this: `https://steamcommunity.com/id/customNameHere` and convert this programatically into a steamID64 like this: `76561197960435530`

I would like to implement this using JavaScript or by using an API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. [Here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/ResolveVanityURL) it says you can use the following syntax to resolve a vanity url:

`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&vanityurl=userVanityUrlName`

Don't quite know why it was hiding on the TF2 wiki though. I could have found it at https://steamapi.xpaw.me/#ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL.